# WPF XAML defined MenuItem reuse starts working, then disappears

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, menuitem, code-reuse

The following simple code attempts to reuse a MenuItem defined in the Window.Resources on two separate Menus.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="menuItemValues">
       <MenuItem Header="First"/>
       <MenuItem Header="Second"/>
       <MenuItem Header="Third"/>
    </collections:ArrayList>
    <MenuItem x:Key="menuItem" x:Shared="False"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource menuItemValues}"
              Header="Shared menu item"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="menuItem"/>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="menuItem"/>
    </Menu>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This starts out great and when you first select the menus, all looks well.  The first menu has the desired MenuItems,

[image]

So does the second:

[image]

But when you navigate back to the first menu, the MenuItems disappear:

[image]

Can someone explain why the menu disappears and a way to get this to work?

This was discovered while investigating another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808867/why-does-an-xarray-element-cause-any-xshared-attribute-following-it-to-be-igno) that was getting an exception.  I tried to use a strategy discussed on [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630645/how-do-i-reuse-item-children-via-a-style-in-xaml) and it seemed to solve the problem until you navigate back to the menu a second time and it disappears.

I have reproduced this issue on 2 separate machines:

1. Win 10, VS2013 Ult V12.0.40629.00 Update 5, .NET V4.6.0138
2. Win 7, VS2013 Prem V12.0.31101.00 Update 4, .NET V4.5.51209

Comment: Considering how it's being used, did you try `DynamicResource` instead of Static?

Comment: @ChrisW. - good suggestion - I just tried switching the tags and it caused `XAMLParseException:  A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

Comment: Ah yea, ItemSource, makes sense. Hmm, I'll try and stew on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because, while the top-level `MenuItem` is `x:Shared="False"`, the `MenuItem` objects in your collection are not. They are declared once each in the `ArrayList` collection, and then reused in each instance of the `menuItem` object that's created.

To get the code to work, you'll need to force WPF to create new instances. One option would be to apply the `x:Shared="False"` to the collection as well. For example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="menuItemValues" x:Shared="False">
       <MenuItem Header="First"/>
       <MenuItem Header="Second"/>
       <MenuItem Header="Third"/>
    </collections:ArrayList>
    <MenuItem x:Key="menuItem" x:Shared="False"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource menuItemValues}"
              Header="Shared menu item"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="menuItem"/>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="menuItem"/>
    </Menu>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Of course, given that the items are simply given `Header` values, you could just use the default `MenuItem` templating behavior, by providing `string` values instead of `MenuItem` values. This allows you to reuse the collection itself (which has no underlying inability for reuse):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="menuItemValues">
      <s:String>First</s:String>
      <s:String>Second</s:String>
      <s:String>Third</s:String>
    </collections:ArrayList>
    <MenuItem x:Key="menuItem" x:Shared="False"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource menuItemValues}"
              Header="Shared menu item"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="menuItem"/>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="menuItem"/>
    </Menu>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Oh ffs, x:shared, face palm, +1 great explanation!