# The tag 'Employee' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:XYZ;assembly=XYZ'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am trying out a simple WPF application. The XAML code is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1"
        Title="My First WPF Demo" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="i">10</sys:Int32>
        <local:Employee x:Key="emp2"></local:Employee> --> THIS LINE
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" FontSize="18" Margin="20"></TextBox>
        <Button x:Name="btnClickMe" FontSize="18" Margin="20" 
                Click="btnClickMe_Click">Click Me</Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblName" FontSize="18" Margin="20"></TextBlock>
        <Label x:Name="lblEmpInfo" FontSize="18" Margin="20"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblEmpInfo2" FontSize="18" Margin="20"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I have a class Employee that is as follows in the same project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When i try to build my project i get the error:

> Error 1   The tag 'Employee' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1'. Line 9
>   Position 10.

Comment: Haven't really checked, but... Have you tried removing the `;assembly=WpfApplication1` part? Leaving only `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"`

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your solution

Comment: Tried that many times. I've even tried restarting visual studio

Comment: I hope you do not have any folders inside your project. only files are there

Comment: Yes, I just added a class. I didn't make any other changes to the structure

Comment: this.DataContext = new Employee(); in your xaml.cs file?

Comment: No i  jsut tried to instantiate it using `<local:Employee x:Key="emp2"></local:Employee>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84366/discussion-between-deshdeep-singh-and-anishajain).

Answer (score 0):

use this way in your case:
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"

Comment: When i removed the assembly value, i get the error `The name 'Employee' doesn't exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfApplication1'`

Comment: @Anisha please try to clean and rebuild your solution this error should not come.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really checked, but... Have you tried removing the `assembly=WpfApplication1` part? Leaving only `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"`

Comment: When i removed the assembly value, i get the error `The name 'Employee' doesn't exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfApplication1'`

Comment: Weird... The error makes no sense at all. Try removing that XAML line, re-building, and adding it again :/

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code (Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012 Update 4) and ran into the same situation. After trying some ideas (some months ago I think had the same issue) the following 'workaround' worked for me:

1. Remove the 'error line' and the namespace from your MainWindow.xaml (but keep your Employee.cs in the Project)
2. Build the solution! (I think Visual Studio needs to build your Employee.cs *before* you can instantiate the object in XAML)
3. Add your Employee and the namespace without the explicit assembly

I'm looking forward hearing whether it fixed the problem

Comment: Found a possible Duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080680/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-strange-b

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question but what worked what this:

I change the tag from

```
<local:MyClass Name="TagName"></local:MyClass>
```

To:

```
<local:MyClass Name="TagName"/>
```

But the following error was thrown:

```
Because 'MyClass' is implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute rather than the Name attribute.
```

So i changed to and worked:

```
<local:MyClass x:Name="TagName"/>
```

And then tried and worked too:

```
 <local:MyClass x:Name="TagName"></local:MyClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Tried to rebuild, clean, restart Visual Studio, rebuild again, but nothing solved the issue. I also removed the `assembly=...` part, it didn't help.

Then I tried moving the project to my hard disk (it was originally in my documents folder, which is located on a mapped network drive), and suddenly the problem was gone! Don't know why, but could be worth a try if anyone else is still having this problem.